# Guineas Dealer ||||||||

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay, anagram

> This visionary turns into a comedian, an animal and a fictional hero
> around Christmas.

What is his favorite machine?

Note: The lines after the word "Dealer" in the title have nothing to do with the puzzle. Only done to fill the 15 character requirement :)

Comment: *"The lines after the word "Dealer" in the title have nothing to do with the puzzle."* But there will be enough characters even after removing the lines.

Comment: Kept getting the min 15 character message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think his favorite machine is

> spaceships/rockets

First, the title

> Is an anagram of the three words - **"A genius leader"**

A visionary

> Made me think of Elon Musk

If we anagram the name Elon, we get

> comedian: Jay **Leno**, animal: **Leon**(meaning lion in greek) and a fictional hero around Christmas: Pére **Noel**(Santa Claus in French)  or as OP stated in the comments: The fictional hero **Lone** Ranger

Comment: Svanyyl gurer vg vf. Bs pbhefr nabgure nantenz vf YBAR juvpu tvirf lbh Ybar Enatre gur svpgvbany ureb.

Comment: Added that in the answer!